# What is the preg_match_all `u` flag dependent on?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have some code in a PHP application that is returning null when I try and use it on the production server, but it works fine on the development server. Here is the line of code:

```
// use the regex unicode support to separate the UTF-8 characters into an array
preg_match_all( '/./us', $str, $match );
```

What is the `u` flag dependent on? I tested with `mb_string` enabled and disabled and it does not seem to affect it.

The error I'm getting is

`preg_match_all: Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset -1`

**more info**

this is one of the options on the prodction server:

`'--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre'`

and here are the pcre sections

[image: Picture.png]

I believe this is the note @Wesley was referring to:

```
In  order  process  UTF-8 strings, you must build PCRE to include UTF-8
support in the code, and, in addition,  you  must  call  pcre_compile()
with  the  PCRE_UTF8  option  flag,  or the pattern must start with the
sequence (*UTF8). When either of these is the case,  both  the  pattern
and  any  subject  strings  that  are matched against it are treated as
UTF-8 strings instead of strings of 1-byte characters.
```

Any links or tips on how to "build PCRE to include UTF-8" ?

[via](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

results of `pcretest -C`

```
PCRE version 6.6 06-Feb-2006
Compiled with
  UTF-8 support
  Unicode properties support
  Newline character is LF
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

Comment: Are you testing against a variable or a constant value? Your example has a variable, I think you should test against a constant to ensure you're doing the same on dev and live.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php, see the comments as well.

Answer (score 5):

This flag depends on PCRE being built with unicode support enabled.

PHP bundles this library and it's normally built with unicode support enabled: The `u` modifier is available and always works since PHP 4.1.0, when PHP is built with the bundled PCRE library.

However some Linux distributions build PHP against their own build of PCRE, which do not have unicode support enabled, and as a result the `u` modifier doesn't work on those builds.

The solution is to use an alternative PHP package.

Comment: What do I look for to know if it was enabled and what language do I use to tell the sysadmin I need it available? I believe the system is based on CentOS.

Comment: You could look for the PCRE_UTF8 macro being defined or not in /usr/include/pcre.h

Comment: i don't have root access on the production machine, but i can get into /usr/include and pcre.h is not there. also updated the question with more info.

Comment: added the results to the question. looks like it is not the same as that bug report since it claims `Unicode properties support`

Comment: maybe php is linked with an other pcre on the system; try running `ldd /usr/bin/php` and look which libpcre it's linked against

Comment: `ldd /usr/bin/php | grep pcre` gives me `libpcre.so.0 => /lib/libpcre.so.0`. not sure what to do with that. if i execute `/lib/libpcre.so.0` it tells me `Segmentation fault`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the PCRE being compiled with --enable-utf8.

Comment: this sounds right - can you elaborate? I don't see that in the php_info for the development or production machine.