# Regex to detect invalid UTF-8 string

Tags: php, regex, validation, utf-8

In PHP, we can use [`mb_check_encoding()`](https://www.php.net/mb_check_encoding) to determine if a string is valid UTF-8. But that's not a portable solution as it requires the mbstring extension to be compiled in and enabled. Additionally, it won't tell us *which* character is invalid.

Is there a regular expression (or another other 100% portable method) that can match invalid UTF-8 bytes in a given string?

That way, those bytes can be replaced if needed (keeping the binary information, such as when building a test output XML file that includes binary data). So converting the characters to UTF-8 would lose information. So, we may want to convert:

```
"foo" . chr(128) . chr(255)
```

Into

```
"foo<128><255>"
```

So just "detecting" that the string is not good enough, we'd need to be able to detect which characters are invalid.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use this PCRE regular expression to check for byte sequences in a string that are not valid UTF-8. If the regex matches, the string contains invalid byte sequences. It's 100% portable because it doesn't rely on PCRE_UTF8 to be compiled in.

```
$regex = '/(
    [\xC0-\xC1] # Invalid UTF-8 Bytes
    | [\xF5-\xFF] # Invalid UTF-8 Bytes
    | \xE0[\x80-\x9F] # Overlong encoding of prior code point
    | \xF0[\x80-\x8F] # Overlong encoding of prior code point
    | [\xC2-\xDF](?![\x80-\xBF]) # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Start
    | [\xE0-\xEF](?![\x80-\xBF]{2}) # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Start
    | [\xF0-\xF4](?![\x80-\xBF]{3}) # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Start
    | (?<=[\x00-\x7F\xF5-\xFF])[\x80-\xBF] # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Middle
    | (?<![\xC2-\xDF]|[\xE0-\xEF]|[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xF0-\xF4]|[\xF0-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]|[\xF0-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]{2})[\x80-\xBF] # Overlong Sequence
    | (?<=[\xE0-\xEF])[\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]) # Short 3 byte sequence
    | (?<=[\xF0-\xF4])[\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]{2}) # Short 4 byte sequence
    | (?<=[\xF0-\xF4][\x80-\xBF])[\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]) # Short 4 byte sequence (2)
)/x';
```

We can test it by creating a few variations of text:

```
// Overlong encoding of code point 0
$text = chr(0xC0) . chr(0x80);
var_dump(preg_match($regex, $text)); // int(1)
// Overlong encoding of 5 byte encoding
$text = chr(0xF8) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x80);
var_dump(preg_match($regex, $text)); // int(1)
// Overlong encoding of 6 byte encoding
$text = chr(0xFC) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x80);        
var_dump(preg_match($regex, $text)); // int(1)
// High code-point without trailing characters
$text = chr(0xD0) . chr(0x01);
var_dump(preg_match($regex, $text)); // int(1)
```

etc...

In fact, since this matches invalid bytes, you could then use it in preg_replace to replace them away:

```
preg_replace($regex, '', $text); // Remove all invalid UTF-8 code-points
```

Comment: @hakre: except that it depends on compile time options (PCRE_UTF8). So it's not portable...

Comment: What do you do if PCRE is not compiled in at all?

Comment: @hakre I thought pcre cannot be disabled at configure time?

Comment: @Jack: It's an extension, you can compile PHP without the PCRE extension. https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-5.4/ext/pcre and `--without-pcre-regex` switch

Comment: It's perhaps worth to change the suggestion at the end to remove invalid sequences and instead replace them with U+FFFD `"\xEF\xBF\xBD"`, see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/#Ill-Formed_Subsequences

Answer (score 11):

Assuming PHP is compiled with PCRE, it most often is also enabled with UTF-8. So as explicitly asked for in the question, this very simple regular expression can detect invalid UTF-8 strings, because those won't match:

```
preg_match('//u', $string);
```

You can then argue that the `u` modifier (PCRE_UTF8) is not always available, and true, this can happen as the this question shows:

- [What is the preg_match_all `u` flag dependent on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7456939/367456)

However, in my practical developer life, this never was an issue. It is more an issue that the PCRE extension is not available at all, which would render any answer containing PCRE as useless (even mine here). But most often that issue was more an issue of the past as of today minus some years.

A more lengthy answer similar to this one has been given in the somehow duplicate question:

- [How can I detect a malformed UTF-8 string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723562)

So I think this question should highlight more of the benefits the suggested answer ships with.

Comment: Is it perhaps the PHP apache module and apache is not compiled with PCRE UTF-8 support?

Answer (score 7):

[The W3C has a page (titled *Multilingual form encoding*)](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8) that lists the following Perl regular expression which **matches a valid UTF-8 string**.

(Note that this is the opposite of the regex listed in another answer to this SO question which matches an *invalid* UTF-8 string.)

```
#  Returns true if $field is UTF-8, and false otherwise.

$field =~
  m/\A(
     [\x00-\x7F]                        # ASCII
   | [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
   |  \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding overlongs
   | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}  # straight 3-byte
   |  \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding surrogates
   |  \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # planes 1-3
   | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
   |  \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # plane 16
  )*\z/x;
```

Comment: This regex doesn't match valid ASCII (control chars)  `[\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]` should be [\x00-\x7F]

Comment: @BradKent Indeed, the W3C page actually says `[\x00-\x7F]` and only shows the more restricted set as a note at the end of the prose. I have edited the answer

Answer (score -1):

This works for me for detecting Unicode characters, linke emoji, Russian or Chinese:

```
private function has_unicode($string)
{
    $pattern = '/^.*[^\x{00}-\x{00FF}]+.*$/u';
    return preg_match($pattern, $string) ? true : false;
}
```