# Removing the "\ufeff" from the end of object -> content in Google+ API json result

Tags: php, json, google-plus

The result from the Google+ API has `\ufeff` appended to the end of every "content" result (I don't really know why?)

What is the best way to remove this unicode character from the json result? It is producing a `'?'` in some of the output I am displaying.

Example:

```
https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/get#try-it
```

enter activity id

```
z12pvrsoaxqlw5imi22sdd35jwvkglj5204
```

and click Execute, result will be:

```
{
 .....
 "object": {
  ......
  "content": "CONTENT OF GOOGLE PLUS POST HERE \ufeff",
  ......
```

example PHP code which shows a '?' where the '\ufeff' is:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($result_from_google_plus_api, true);
echo $data['object']['content'];
// outputs "CONTENT OF GOOGLE PLUS POST HERE ?"
echo trim($data['object']['content']);
// outputs "CONTENT OF GOOGLE PLUS POST HERE ?"
```

Or am I going about this the wrong way? Should I be fixing the '?' issue rather than trying to remove the `'\ufeff'`?

Comment: It's quite unusual to see a BOM at the end of a string ...

Comment: In general, you can filter all invalid utf-8 characters by using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11709412/1338292).

Comment: @Jack except that `\ufeff` is valid UTF-8 and will not be caught by the answer you posted

Answer (score 10):

In your case, you could use this regexp:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\x{feff}$/u', '', $str);
```

That way you can exactly match that code point value and have it removed.

From my experience there are a lot more white-spacey-character you want to remove. From *my* experienced this works well for *me*:

```
# I like to call this unicodeTrim()
$str = preg_replace(
  '/
    ^
    [\pZ\p{Cc}\x{feff}]+
    |
    [\pZ\p{Cc}\x{feff}]+$
   /ux',
  '',
  $str
);
```

I found http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html a pretty good resource about the fine details:

- `\pZ` - match any kind of whitespace or invisible separator
- `\p{Cc}` - match control characters
- `\x{feff}` - match BOM

I've seen regex suggest to match `\pC` instead of `\pCc`, however this is dangerous because `pC` includes *any code point to which no character has been assigned*. I've had actual data (certain emojis or other stuff) being removed because of this.

But, YMMW, I cant' stress this.

Comment: Thanks mark! I'm a few weeks off getting back to this project, once I do I'll implement this regex and let you know how it goes :) cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**By Respect to All Answers**

---

I test most of answers but finally find solution here:  [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/josephspurrier/8780545)

```
$field = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $field);
```