# Perl regex to replace invalid UTF-8 characters in string

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8

I have the following code that can detect non-valid utf-8 characters in a string
(regex taken from https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8 and [Regex to detect invalid UTF-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709410/regex-to-detect-invalid-utf-8-string))

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

my @Strings=('Caractéristiques techniques','Test string 1');
foreach my $ival (@Strings){        
    my $TestA=eval{$ival =~
    /\A(
    [\x00-\x7F]                          # ASCII
    | [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
    |  \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding overlongs
    | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}  # straight 3-byte
    |  \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding surrogates
    |  \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # planes 1-3
    | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
    |  \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # plane 16
    )*\z/x};        
    if(defined $TestA){ 
        print "$ival is valid utf-8!\n";
    } else {
        print "$ival is NOT valid utf-8!\n";
    }       
}
```

I now need some code to replace any invalid characters found with a valid utf-8 user defined character.

Logically, I need a regex to replace everything EXCEPT those values in my validation regex but I don't know how to do this.

I know that to replace all characters EXCEPT 'a to z' and 'A to Z' I can use `$ival=~s/[^a-zA-Z]//g;` But I don't know how to extend this concept to the regex in my code.

Note: I do have some strings that contain non-valid utf-8 characters but they are not given here)

Comment: Can you add some sample input with vald + non valid utf8 and the expected output?

Comment: Unfortunately not! The data that contains non-utf 8 characters is stored in a database table that I am scanning. If I try and print this data to the screen, garbage is returned and I don't know how to add a non utf-8 character to my perl test script

Comment: You need `use utf8::all` in your script. `use utf8` is not sufficient. If you get `Can't locate utf8/all.pm in @INC`, you need to install the module with  `cpan utf8::all`.

Comment: And  please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Better use a sharing web site like gist to store the file

Comment: Just a note:  This pattern is really good. It considers the following bad: Surrogates, overlong sequences, characters above U+10FFFF. And of course, just plain junk.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `decode` replaces invalid bytes with U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER. So you could use

```perl
my $text_ucp = decode( 'UTF-8', $text_utf8 ) =~ s/\N{ REPLACEMENT CHARACTER }//gr;
```

(`\N{ REPLACEMENT CHARACTER }`, `\N{ U+FFFD }` and `\x{FFFD}` would all work.)

---

Alternatively, it can be achieved using a simple modification to your pattern.

```perl
$text_utf8 =~ s/
   (?! (?&VALID_UTF8_SEQ) ) .

   (?(DEFINE)
      (?<VALID_UTF8_SEQ>
         (?: [\x00-\x7F]                        # ASCII
         |   [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
         |   \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]         # excluding overlongs
         |   [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}  # straight 3-byte
         |   \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]         # excluding surrogates
         |   \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}      # planes 1-3
         |   [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
         |   \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}      # plane 16
         )
      )
   )
//xs;

utf8::decode( my $text_ucp = $text_utf8 );
```

The following is surely much more efficient:

```perl
$text_utf8 =~ s/
   (?&VALID_UTF8_SEQ)+(*SKIP)(*FAIL) | .

   (?(DEFINE)
      (?<VALID_UTF8_SEQ>
         (?: [\x00-\x7F]                        # ASCII
         |   [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
         |   \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]         # excluding overlongs
         |   [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}  # straight 3-byte
         |   \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]         # excluding surrogates
         |   \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}      # planes 1-3
         |   [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
         |   \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}      # plane 16
         )
      )
   )
//xs;

utf8::decode( my $text_ucp = $text_utf8 );
```

That said, actually negating is pretty easy given the properties of UTF-8.

```perl
$text_utf8 =~ s/
   (?: [\x80-\xC1\xF5-\xFF]
   |   [\xC2-\xDF]           (?! [\x80-\xBF] )
   |   \xE0                  (?! [\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF] )
   |   [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF]   (?! [\x80-\xBF]{2} )
   |   \xED                  (?! [\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF] )
   |   \xF0                  (?! [\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2} )
   |   [\xF1-\xF3]           (?! [\x80-\xBF]{3} )
   |   \xF4                  (?! [\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2} )
   )+
//xs;

utf8::decode( my $text_ucp = $text_utf8 );
```